# Outdoors Alchemy

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

As a part of a module, our low-level party was sent on some random island with just 10 gp worth of gear each. The logical conclusion from that - as long as we want to have good stuff, we have to do it ourselves.

My character has some ranks in Alchemy and Poisonmaking, so he can do some nasty stuff even in the given situation - but I need to be sure that I understand the alchemy rules well enough.
I assume that if PC can't buy or use someone's else Alchemy Lab, he is stuck with -2 to his roll since he is improvising. If he gets other people to help - how much he gets for any trained helper? What about untrained?  And does he really need to make every Acid flask for several days of doing nothing but this (unless he rolled enough to shorten the item creation time)?

Comment: Even at level 1, 10 gp is a small *fraction* of the expected wealth by level (starting gold is frequently greater than 100 gp). Personally, since I care quite a bit about balance, I would want to be very clear whether the DM intended to maintain this dramatic wealth shortage, and if so, what systemic changes he was making to account for it. Be very careful about low-wealth in 3.5; many aspects of the games already-precarious balance respond very poorly to it.

Comment: As far as I understood, he plans for us to get everything from scratch, by dungeoncrawling and such - so, for now we're carrying clubs, daggers, rations and no armor, useful items or stuff like that. And one may FORGET 'bout getting pre-crafted items. So, yeah XD

Comment: It seems like for a time being he's going to throw enemies of lower CR at our not very magic party. And "Survival Game" with limited resources and stuff is, well, at least not boring, unless you're playing guys like Archivist. Of course, it seems like, for starters, we'll have to find a way to make this weird party cooperate XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Alchemist’s Lab grants a +2 to Craft (alchemy) checks, but lack of one does not cause a −2 penalty:

> Without this lab, a character with the Craft (alchemy) skill is assumed to have enough tools to use the skill but not enough to get the +2 bonus that the lab provides.

People can help with a skill check by using the Aid Another action: provided they succeed on a DC 10 check, they may provide you with a +2 bonus. Multiple helpers can all perform Aid Another, giving you a stacking +2 bonus, though this is limited by however many people you can reasonably have actually helping you.

The other thing to be concerned about is that there are no rules for foraging the materials necessary to craft items. Whether or not you can do so and how much time it takes will be entirely up to your DM. I would try to clarify with your DM what you can expect before starting play.

Also, if you haven’t, you should take Master of Poisons (*Drow of the Underdark*). It’s a great feat for low-level poisoners: you don’t risk poisoning yourself, and you may apply a poison as a Swift action. The [Arsenic & Old Lace: Poison Handbook](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=2714.0) may prove extremely useful to you.

Comment: So, I guess, it would be pretty damn nice to get everyone involved in creating that stuff... I guess, it'd be better to start with cheap poisons which use gold per day instead of silver per day progressions... Just have to make sure that everyone helps... And yeah, Master of Poisons looks great and I planned to take it - until DM said "no flaws", after which I had to make sure that I take something a little bit more... Dedicated to survival XD

Comment: @Baka-Mastermind honestly, I can't think of too many feats that would have higher priority for me than Master of Poisons for a character that ever planned to use the stuff.

Comment: One word: Darkstalker for dedicated sneaker. No, wait, that's four words XD

Comment: On a desert island, will you have *any* tools at all? I can't imagine 10gp is going to get you many retorts, alembics, flasks, stills, etc. I would be worried that your DM is going to rule you can't do anything (except maybe picking plants and chewing them and spitting them into a wooden bowl, like kava :-).